# ng-repeat without an html element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am trying to generate a blog list but i got a problem with ng-repeat. my list looks like this

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
    <span class="sep2"></sep>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
    <span class="sep2"></sep>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Message</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So after every 2 list items, i have a span that levels my next 2 boxes.
Right now i have this angular code.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in postsJSON">
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.message}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And i dont know how to generate that span after every second list item.
Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Comment: do you really need the `span`? Seems like this could be done with `nth-child` css selector. Also `span` in `ul`?

Comment: my posts are on 3 columns, each one having a different height, if i dont use a span with 100% width, the ones under the first ones will position wierd. and i can't use a table because my layout is responsive and the 3 column turns to 2 column on ipad.

Comment: You might want to post your css too, or setup a plunker/fiddle. This really seems more like a css than a js problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With angular v1.2 it becomes quite easy, using `ng-repeat-start`, `ng-repeat-end` and `ng-if`, you can check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/XNJvj/1/

Your code will look like this:

```
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat-start='post in postsJSON'>
            {{post.item}}<br/>
            {{post.message}}
        </li>
        <span ng-if="$odd && !$first" ng-repeat-end>
            <span class="sep2">_____</span>
        </span>
    </ul>
```

`ng-repeat-start/end` allows you to enter a loop in a tag and close it in another, in this case, I also added a condition using the $odd parameter of the `ng-repeat`, showing only every other span

Comment: yet the `span` should not be a child of `ul`. ;)

Comment: That's true, I just provide a solution to the exposed issue, this will generate the code asked, even if it was against conventions before ;) I'd also use something like nth-child, but without any css or more content, it's difficult to advice

Comment: you're right about that, +1 for showing a new feature of angular 1.2!

Comment: thank you very much, i used this and it works perfect :) i dont use nth:child because of IE8

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not really with angular but more with the structure of your markup. ul tag should normally only contains li tags as children.

To resolve your issue I will stick to the ng-repeat you already have and create the separator with css. Something like that :

```
<ul class="blog list">
    <li ng-repeat="post in postsJSON" class="blog entry">
        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
        <p>{{post.message}}</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

```
.blog.entry {
  border-bottom : 1px solid black // or whatever color
  ...
}
```

or if you need more control on the separator use css :after and do something like

```
.blog.entry:after {
  content : "";
  ...
 }
```

If you are not familiar with :after you can have a look [there](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)